# porque no me pinta nada en el emulador

Tags: android, api, react-native, axios

Estoy tratando de consumir una api, pero no me pinta nada en el emulador android trato que me la ponga en una lista o al dar clic en un botón me mande la data de la api, pero solo me la muestra en la consola :( ¿qué más me falta para pintarlo en el emulador andrid?

este es el codigo que llevo.

```
import axios, { Axios } from "axios";
import {SafeAreaView, FlatList, Text} from "react-native";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {      
    const [usuarios, setUsuarios]= useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
      axios({url: "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2"}) 
        .then ((response)=>{
         console.log(response.data)
        });
      }, []);

    };
```

Comment: Primero asegura que tu información se está obteniendo adecuadamente, que se muestra cuando imprimes console.log(response.data) ?

Comment: @jorgesys, el console.log(response.data) me muestra la data de la api pero solo en la consola (uso visual studio code) y no logro que esa data me la pinte en el emulador android.